# GMail compose e-mail replace variables

Tags: gmail

Is it possible to send an e-mail with variables in GMail?

I would like to do something like:

```
Hello %email%,
```

In this example I would like %email% to be replaced with the actual e-mail which recieves my e-mail. This should also work, if I send to multiple receivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do this. I spoke with Google earlier today about it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for mail merge functionality. Are you speaking about the native Gmail web client? If so, the answer is no. If not, please clarify your question.

You could do something like this though, http://www.labnol.org/internet/personalized-mail-merge-in-gmail/20981/

Search for Gmail mail merge and you can find some other solutions.

Comment: It looks interesting. And yes, I'm using the native Gmail webclient. I want this veriable replaced in all my e-mails and not have to create a spreadsheet for every time I want to send an e-mail. The ideal flow would be to go to compose and type in Hello %email%.